# How to use DataContractSerializer efficiently with this use case?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to use the powerful DataContractSerializer to write or read data to the XML file.

But as my concept, DataContractSerializer can only read or write data with entire structure or list of structure.

My use case is describe below....I cannot figure out how to optimize the performance by using this API.

I have a structure named "Information" and have a `List<Information>` with unexpectable number of elements in this list.

User may update or add new element into this list very often.

Per operation (Add or Update), I must serialize all the element in the list to the same XML file.

So, I will write the same data even they are not modified into XML again. It does not make sense but I cannot find any approach to avoid this happened.

Due to the tombstoning mechanism, I must save all the information in 10 secs.

I'm afraid of the performance and maybe make UI lag...

Could I use any workaround to partially update or add a data information into the XML file by DataContractSerializer?

Answer (score 0):

DataContractSerializer can be used to serialize selected items - what you need to do is to come up with scheme to identify changed data and way to efficiently serialize it. For example, one of the way could be

1. You start by serializing entire list of structures to an file.
2. Whenever some object is added/updated/removed from list, you create a diff object that will identify kind of change and the object changed. Then you can serialize this object to xml and append the xml to file.
3. While reading the file, you may have to apply similar logic, first read list and then start applying diffs one after another.
4. Because you want to continuous append to file, you shouldn't have root element in your file. In other words, the file with diff info will not be an valid xml document. It would contain series of xml fragments. To read it, you have to enclose these fragments in a xml declaration and root element.
5. You may use some background task to write the entire list periodically to generate valid xml file. At this point, you may discard your diff file. Idea is to mimic transactional system - one data structure to have serialized/saved info and then another structure containing changes (akin to transaction log).

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a concern then using something other than DataContractSerializer.

There is a good comparison of the options at 
http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/11/03/wp7-serialization-comparison/

If the size of the list is a concern, you could try breaking it into smaller lists. THe most appropriate way to do this will depend on the data in your list and typical usage/edit/addition patterns.

Depending on the frequency with which the data is changed you could try saving it whenever it is changed. This would remove the need to save it in the time available for deactivation.